# Selecting MAX number from MySQL table not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked this up and I've yet to figure this out. This is part of my [table.](http://puu.sh/cV7d0/1cf0ef3c12.png)

What I'm trying to do is, grab the biggest number in the tradeNum column. What I have so far is:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(tradeNum) FROM trades";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "num: " . $row["tradeNum"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

While this doesn't echo "0 results," it echos nothing. I'm still new to mysql, but shouldn't this work? I took most of the code from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) if it helps. Sorry if I'm vague, let me know if I need to clear something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you query should be

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(tradeNum) AS tradeNum FROM trades";
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch! I knew it was something simple.

Comment: yeah, you just needed to give the total the same column name as the key you are using :)   Please do not forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: It says I have to wait 8 minutes. I will when I can though!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(tradeNum) tradeNum FROM trades"; // here use tradeNum as alias
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result[0]['tradeNum'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `tradeNum` column to get the data, you can as well use `order by` with `limit`

```
SELECT tradeNum FROM trades order by tradeNum desc limit 1
```